# Error authenticating a web application with OpenID Provider using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect

I'm trying to authenticate web application using third party configured Open ID Connect provider using Spring boot 2.
Once I enter the login credentials and submit, during code exchange, I get this error

`org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse] and content type [text/html]`

I'm kind of stuck at this point. I'm following this blog[enter link description here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect)
Below is the yaml and pom file.

application.yml

```
    logging: 
      level: 
        org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    spring: 
      security: 
        oauth2: 
          client: 
            provider: 
              abc: 
                authorization-uri: https://xyz/oauth/authorize
                token-uri: https://xyz/oauth/token
                user-info-uri: https://xyz/oauth/userinfo
                user-name-attribute: sub
                jwk-set-uri: https://xyz/oauth/jwks/jwk-url
            registration: 
              abc: 
                authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
                client-id: ****
                client-secret: ****
                scope: openid,profile,email
                redirect-uri: https://xyz/login/oauth2/code/abc
```

pom.xml

```
    

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The redirect-uri is registered with the server and works fine, once I submit credentials, I get the code as response.
While exchanging the code, the request procesing fails.
I would appreciate any help to move forward and solve this error.

This is my config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth2/**","/login/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().oauth2Login()

    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class SwController {
    
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SwController.class);
    
    @GetMapping("/user/oidc-principal")
    @CrossOrigin
    public OidcUser user(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser principal) { 
        return principal; 
    }
}
```

Comment: the error message is telling you that the response you are getting back from the service is most likely a webpage or an error page `[text/html]`

Comment: yeah, seems so, because the service should have returned a json format data consisting of access_token, refresh_token and other.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I did check my /token endpoint with the code returned by authorization endpoint, and it works. It returns the expected json response, but fails in spring.

Comment: Trace logs should tell you what you have done wrong.

Comment: @Toerktumlare the stack trace error, I have already mentioned in this post.

Comment: no you posted just the error stack trace. I was asking for the `TRACE` logs, thats something else.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem here was not in the Spring Boot code, but in the service itself. The third party service provider's domain had an issue, which resulted in [text/html] page being returned. And since Spring was expecting application/json response from this service , it couldn't find the suitable httpmessageconverter to handle this request.